# can you set an exception for nginx's requests per second limit?

Tags: nginx, request, limit

We try to save nginx resources by limiting the number of requests per second:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=gulag:10m  rate=2r/s;

    server
    {
        location / {
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8181;
         limit_req   zone=gulag  burst=40;
        }
    }
}
```

However, most employees in our company are also heavy users of our own website.  Since everyone in the company appear to come from the same ip address were getting 503 errors because nginx thinks all the traffic is coming from one user.  Can we add our ip as an exception to the requests per second limit?

Comment: Why not combine ip to a cookie tracker system rather than using an exception? (please notify me @ i don't check the answers)

Comment: @user2284570 Can you explain how that would work?

Comment: It means you'll work by identifying the client program directly instead of it's ip.

Comment: @user2284570 So would I just do my limiting at the application level and not with nginx?  Do you have any helpful links?

Comment: No,you'll steel to do it on the web server. Cookies are just one example: You see 'This page is using cookies. [Read more](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/55)' on many website like this [one.](http://rpm.pbone.net/) It allow advertiser to identify the web browser directly. If the web-browser delete it's cookies then it's IP associated with it is compared.<br> So advertiser can track browsing habits of several users which use the same ip.<br>Of course they don't only use cookies/associated IP,but this all I currently know. In your case it will also allow your site working with big proxies.

Comment: @user2284570 looks like nginx use to allow restrictions by cookies but the documentation referenced here is obsolete... http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/How-to-use-cookie-for-request-conection-limiting-td3916437.html

Comment: Sorry, I've currently no experience for doing this. I'll check this when I'll have time at the end of the week. Instead of Sending an error page, I would go ahead an add a filter rule in the firewall (by launching an external command like iptables). It is lot off more efficient against DDOS attacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just a quote from [the documentation](http://nginx.org/r/limit_req_zone):

> The key is any non-empty value of the specified variable (**empty values are not accounted**).

So you can achieve your goal by using [geo](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) and [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) modules like this:

```
geo $limited_net {
    default      1;
    10.1.0.0/16  0;
}

map $limited_net $addr_to_limit {
    0  "";
    1  $binary_remote_addr;
}

limit_req_zone  $addr_to_limit  zone=gulag:10m  rate=2r/s;
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  I executed nginx -V and it doesn't look like these modules are installed by default.  I'll recompile tomorrow and verify your answer.

Comment: Well I recommend to you use official packages. They definitely have these modules: http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

Comment: btw, to build these modules you don't need any special configure parameters

Comment: So are you saying those modules are installed by default?  I can just use them in my nginx config?

Comment: Yes, unless your nginx has compiled with the `--without-http_map_module` and `--without-http_geo_module` options.

Comment: The problem with this technique is that you would block Tor nodes and many web proxies.

Comment: This solution isn't working for me. An excluded IP address is still subject to rate limits. Any idea why, or what we can do to debug it?